# C# regex question - help

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I get MB of transfer left from this string?

```
<div class="loggedIN"> 
Jesteś zalogowany jako: <a href="konto" style="color:#ffffff;"><b>Hooch</b></a> <i>|</i> <a style="font-size:11px;" href="wyloguj">wyloguj się </a><br/><br/> 
Transfer: 21410.73 MB<br/><span title="Dziennie limit ściąganie z RS zwiększany jest o 500MB, kumuluje się maksymalnie do 2500MB. Podczas pobierania z RS, limit jest obniżany a transfer pobierany jest z konta podstawowego.">z czego max 2500 MB na RS <a href="konto,rs"><img src="style/img/ico/info_icon.png" border="0"/></a></span><br/> 
</div>
```

I don't know how regex have look to get one group with this: "21410.73"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Match m = Regex.Match(string, @"Transfer: ([0-9.]+) MB");
if (m.Success)
{
    string remaining = m.Groups[1].Value
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 4):

Using regular expression for that seems overkill. Just look for the string `"Transfer: "` and then look for the following `" MB"`, and get what's between:

```
int start = str.IndexOf("Transfer: ") + 10;
int end = str.IndexOf(" MB", start);
string mb = str.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Comment: +1 Just because you aren't using Regexes. (RANT MODE ON) I'm quite tired of persons that don't know how to compose Regexes and try to use them even to go to the bathroom... I've programmed for more than 10 years before learning Regexes and I was always happy with strstr, strcpy... Why now everyone wants to use regexes?

Comment: I want regex. It looks nicer.

Comment: @Hooch If you want nicer take a Mac. Code must be maintainable. If you can't write Regexes, you don't write Regexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"Transfer: ([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)");
var result = rx.Match(html).Groups[1].Value;
```

BUT you shouldn't parse html with Regex. I'm "anchoring" the regex to the "Transfer: " string.

Answer (score -1):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(string, @"Transfer: [0-9.]+ MB$");
if (match.Success)
   var dataLeft = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

I often use  this online tester for my reg-ex tests : http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: My guess is: you are not actually capturing the number, and MB is not at the end of the string (so do not use $).